# How to fix some damages from site hack?

Tags: google-search-console, hacked-site

My site had been hacked. I found the vulnerability, fixed it, and removed shell scripts.
But the hacker had uploaded thousands of web pages on my web server. After I removed those pages I got over 4 thousand "Not Found" pages on my site (all linked from an external free domain and host which is removed now). Also hundreds of keywords had been added to my site. After 3 weeks I can still see keywords from removed pages on my Google Webmaster Tools.

I had 1st result on Google Search for certain keywords but now I am on 3rd page for the same keywords. 50% of my traffic was from Google which is now reduced to 6%.

**How can I fix both those "Not Found" pages problem and new useless keywords?** And **will it be enough to get me back on first result on Google?**

P.S:

- Both vulnerability and uploaded files are certainly removed.
- My site is not infected, checked on Google Webmaster and a few other security web scan tools.
- All files had been uploaded on one directory so I got something like `example.com/hacked/page1.html` and `example.com/hacked/webpage2.html`.

Comment: after over 2 weeks NOT FOUND problem is not solved. I didn't get to top results for my main keywords again. but keywords from removed pages are no longer on "Google's webmaster Keyword Page". Is there any thing else that I should do(pages are blocked by robot.txt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59819

> Do I need to make changes to content I want removed from Google?
>
> If you wish to remove your content using the URL removal request tool in our Google Webmaster Tools, you must first meet the criteria listed below.
>
> To remove a page or image, you must do one of the following:
>
> - Make sure the content is no longer live on the web. Requests for the page must return an HTTP 404 (not found) or 410 status code.
> - Block the content using a robots.txt file.
> - Block the content using a meta noindex tag.
>
> To remove a directory and its contents, or your whole site, you must ensure that the pages you want to remove have been blocked using a robots.txt file. Returning a 404 isn't enough, because it's possible for a directory to return a 404 status code, but still serve out files underneath it. Using robots.txt to block a directory ensures that all of its children are disallowed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Request the SPAM pages are removed from google's index using [webmaster tools](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663637) and return [410 Gone status](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-410-gone/) for the pages rather than a 404s.

Google will get the message that the poor content is gone, but it will take a while for the whole thing to come back together.